# application failure on similar devices

Tags: android

I debug with a Samsung Galaxy SII, running 2.3.6.  I created an app that runs fine, every time, even under stress, on this device.  I uploaded for a colleague in another state, using a device with 2.3.7 (I believe it's a Nexus One).

On his device, the app gives a "Not responding - Force Close or Wait" dialog when clicking a button that switches a ListView's adapter between 2 DB Cursors.

I tried on the emulator.  Literally an hour and 45 minutes later (most of this time was spent converting JSON from a remote server to a local SQLite DB on the device, which happens only once during install, and I don't believe has any bearing on the issue I'm describing), I was able to recreate the problem, but nothing was reported in logcat.

Any ideas why I'm seeing this different results?  My device works every time, his fails every time.  I've tried targetting 2.1 and 2.2 - both have the same results on both devices and the emulator.

TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the devices had different SQLite implementations.  The issue was resolved by adding a missing index to one of the SQLite tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in the past. My app is failing on the HTC device and working fine on google experience phone and emulators. Fortunately for me, both devices are mine and I was able to track down the problem after some digging. The cause is some differences in implementation of UI(HTC sense) and a few basic applications. My app fails because surprisingly, HTC is doing a good job of tightening up some loose code.It is a bit of a corner case. So, you need to have access to that device or give him a special build with writing Log to a file and send you back the file for you to debug.